# Android How to fetch yahoo Contacts

Tags: android, yahoo, yahoo-mail

i want to fetch the yahoo contacts from my android app, if i click the button it has to ask for log in to yahoo, after successful logging in we can able to fetch the contacts, is there any way to do like that  or any sample code, please guide me, thanks in advance.

Comment: hey i want the same but not getting any hint

Comment: Still not getting anything, if you get code any stuffs please post it.

Comment: sure dude i have to find also of Hotmail but also not getting

Comment: Did you get access permissions of yahoo. If not first get access permissions of yahoo then you can fetch contacts.

Comment: thanks for your response, but how to get access permission, can you explain little bit more please, thanks in advance.

Comment: I also want same for yahoo and not getting any hint

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/ and sign up as a developer.

http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/ysp_api_book.html For some more information.

Regarding to examples, there really are tons and tonnes of them out there. Either use their rest service directly or implement the SDK available at: http://developer.yahoo.com/social/sdk/index.html